# How to get a Modal window to open by tapping on particular text

Tags: javascript, css

I have code for a css modal ( which consists of html , css and JavaScript ) wherein it creates a button and tapping on that button opens a modal window

I want to know how do i enable the same functionality for any text of my choice - eg like we use hyperlink. I just want tapping on a particular text to open modal window

I would appreciate lot if someone can edit my codes  and give me the changed codings rather than just giving the raw codes to implement this ( It might be difficult for me as i am very new to this )

Thanks in advance

```
<h2>Enable Modal Window to open through this text</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal1">• Click Me</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <p><span class="headertext">Modal Header Text</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<p><span class="bodytext">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span></p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Enable Modal Window to open through this text</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal2">• Click Me</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <p><span class="headertext">Modal Header Text</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<p><span class="bodytext">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span></p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #171B20;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #F0B823;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #171B20;
    color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bodytext {
   font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;                                                                                                                                  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 35%;
 }
}

p {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
} 





// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may create a function in `javascript` to open the modal. then you can use that function where you need to click on

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying , although i am not familiar with JavaScript   i got all these codes from w3 school.      Can you point out the exact changes needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap but you can also achieve the same by changing little bit in your code.

Here is the working code, 
Things changed. 
1) Added Class and href attribute to  tag.
2) Changed the script where you are selecting all the buttons, instead read control of all type.

```js
$(function(){

// Get the button that opens the modal
// read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
})
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #171B20;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #F0B823;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #171B20;
    color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bodytext {
   font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;                                                                                                                                  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 35%;
 }
}

p {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class='modal-button' href="#myModal1">Enable Modal Window to open through this text</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal1">• Click Me</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <p><span class="headertext">Modal Header Text</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<p><span class="bodytext">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span></p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Enable Modal Window to open through this text</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal2">• Click Me</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <p><span class="headertext">Modal Header Text</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<p><span class="bodytext">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span></p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in order to run it i have added external jquery reference, you can skip that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted, it seems that you stumbled on some bootstrap examples. Bootstrap is a front-end framework. More info on it can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/

In order for bootstrap modals to open, you also need to include the bootstrap javascript file.

The modal specific documentation can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/

Comment: Well thanks for replying.  I had just got the codes from w3 school.   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp.           I don't know much as i am a total newbie although I didn't find bootstrap written anywhere in the above tutorial.   Although i am aware modals can be implemented using bootstrap too

Comment: My bad than. Looking at the class names I thought it was bootstrap. And since W3 schools also has some stuff on bootstrap I figured it sould be possible. If you only need a simple modal, don't go the bootstrap way. It's a bit overkill for just that.